# SOQL - Better query needed as well as field label in list

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller, map

I am trying to figure out how to write this as a better query.

Current thinking: (each field has a count of records for that State)

```
Select AL__c,AK__c, etc FROM Account WHERE...;
```

and then somehow transform that into a list where each field (label or api name) becomes a value.

Want I want in the end is a two dimensional set with all my state values in it:
Example:

```
State, Account
AL, 200
AK, 15
```

This will be shown on a visualforce page as a table.

Edit : Idea! How about something like this? I am getting a "Initial term of field expression must be a concreaet sObject: list" error.

```
 selectedAccount = '001S000000qTmDxIAK';
    map <string,string>     mapStates   = new map<string,string>();
    list <Account> accStates = new list<Account>(
    [Select AL__c,AK__c FROM Account WHERE ID = :selectedAccount]);
    mapStates.add('AL', accStates.AL__c);
mapStates.add('AK', accStates.AK__c);
```

Comment: Like a `Map<String, List<Account>>()`?

Comment: I am just showing the state counts for one particular account. So I don't need the state name as part of it. I just need the state name (abbreviation) and the count from the field.  I could write some really bad looping soql and get there but I don't want to do that.

Comment: I keep getting this thought in my head "Instead of doing a ForEach on the Account, I want to do a ForEach for the 50 state fields". Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: Sure, but that needs to be put, not add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOQL isn't the right tool for the job. In fact, if you use a **[`Field Set`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm), you don't need to write any `Apex` at all!

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.State_Fields}" var="field">
            <apex:column headerValue="State" value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields[field].label}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Account" value="{!Account[field]}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

If you really want this structure in `Apex`, you can still use it in `Apex`:

```
Map<String, Decimal> states = new Map<String, Decimal>();
for (FieldSetMember member : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.State_Fields)
    states.put(member.getLabel(), accountRecord.get(member.getFieldPath());
```

The simplest way to get these variables is through the `StandardController`, whether you're currently doing so or not:

```
public Account record { get; private set; }
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    List<String> fields = new List<String>();
    for (FieldSetMember member : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.State_Fields)
        fields.add(member.getFieldPath();
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(fields);
    record = (Account)controller.getRecord();
}
```

Of course, you can query for it yourself if you wish. You would need to pull the Id in through page parameters most likely:

```
public static final String ID_PARAM = 'Id';
public Account record { get; private set; }
public MyController()
{
    Id recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().parameters.get(ID_PARAM);
    if (recordId == null) return;

    // same fields collection
    record = (Account)Database.query(
        'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' FROM Account WHERE Id = :recordId'
    );
}
```

Comment: I am leaving this answer marked as best but I still don't understand this code and I get errors with the FOR statement. I am going to use the other method I found using the suggestion by @EricSSH to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Are you trying to display a single `Account` or a collection? Also feel free to ask additional questions to clarify. I can't really help you when all you tell me is "I get errors".

Comment: I am not trying to display the account at all. Here is the overall goal explained as best as I can.  We have Enrollers (aka salespeople) who are licensed for individual states. I am creating an email report that conveys this statement in table form.  "Enroller Bob was added to account ABC. This account has employees in states: KS, KY, GA. Enroller Bob is not licensed for GA. "

Comment: Object Structure: Account > Enroller > License.            | The Account page has states fields that are updated daily by batch code. The Enroller has license records for each state.